# ⊢ in contrast to implication

Tags: notation, natural-deduction

so I have read some topics on this but I am still in doubt. I am trying to solve some natural deduction exercices and I am not quite sure what is the difference in how I approach them and the difference in notation, in pratical terms is having ⊢ the same as implication?

For example I have this exercise ⊢ (p => q) => (r + p => r + q) which I resolved like this:

p => q

--assume r + p

------assume r

------r + q

------therefore r => r + q

------assume p

------q

------r + q

------therefore p=> r + q

--r + q

--r + p => r + q

(p => q) => r + p => r + q

Hopefully thats not too hard to understand since I dont know how to properly format here, anyways so I did that one like that and then I have these kinds of exercises :

p => q ⊢ ((p => (p & q)) & ((p & q) => q)

and that one but from the second expression to the first so

((p => (p & q)) & ((p & q) => q) ⊢ p => q

, my question is can I work with these as if the  ⊢ is an implication, are they different? what's the approach here.

Comment: No : $\vdash \varphi$ means that we have proved (in the calculus) the formula $\varphi$.

Comment: But in Natural Deduction we have the $\to$ intro rule that says : if we have  the derivation $\Gamma, \alpha \vdash \varphi$, then we may "transform" it into the new derivation : $\Gamma \vdash \alpha \to \varphi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, *implication* is an ambiguous word...

The connective $\to$ into $p \to q$ is read : " if $p$, then $q$ ".

The symbol $⊢ \varphi$ means that we have proved (in the calculus) the formula $\varphi$.

In your proof, up to the last but one line, you have produced the derivation :

> $p \to q \vdash r \lor p$

because the derivation has the open assumption $p \to q$.

In the last step you have used the rule $\to$-intro to perform the last step :

> $\vdash (p \to q) \to (r \lor p)$.

Thus, we have a "strong link" between the two, but they are different : $\to$ is a *connective* used in the calculus with sentences (i.e. with sentence letters standing for sentences) to generate "more complex" sentences, while $\vdash$ is a symbol (followed by the name of a formula) used in the theory to describe the basic property of the calculus : the existence of a derivation ending with the said formula.

Comment: Alright, think I got it, thanks!